# display list item when a field is not empty

Tags: custom-list

I have custom list, created a view. In that view there is column called response, this is multiline text field. I want to display the list item when it is non empty.

Note: I have created a other view which can display item when the value is empty by specifiying

When Column Contains is blank(no condition, empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemeted the functionality using the following logic in designer!. This displays  the logged in user requests where a column called "response" is NOTNULL. Response of type MultiLine Textbox.

** To Display a view with Multline NotNull Field and created by Current Logged User**

```
SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;And&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Author&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Integer&quot;&gt;&lt;UserID/&gt;&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;IsNotNull&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Response&quot;/&gt;&lt;/IsNotNull&gt;&lt;
```

** To Display a view with Multline Null Field and created by Current Logged User**

```
   SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;And&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Author&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Integer&quot;&gt;&lt;UserID/&gt;&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;IsNotNull&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Response&quot;/&gt;&lt;/IsNull&gt;&lt;
```

Answer (score 4):

In SharePoint Designer open your list. In the area to the right for Views click "new".

Create a new view and then right click it and select edit in advanced mode.

Change `<Query />` to

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="response" /></IsNotNull>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Save your changes and check the results in your new view.

Comment: Robert, thanks for you answer about how to add code in Designer to filter the NULL field. It worked great. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very cheap workaround, but you could search for any times the field contains one of the vowels (a,e,i,o,u,y).  Similar to this:

[image: Search for any instance of a vowel]

Comment: Sharepoint is not very handy!

Comment: I like to think of SharePoint as a big logic puzzle where you always have to think outside-the-box.

Comment: Clever workaround, wouldn't have thought of something like that!

Comment: Just for anyone else reading this and thinking WTF? you can only use Contains and Begins with on *multi* line text fields.

Comment: This is a kind of silly way of doing this.

Comment: Ryan - If you use the method of editing the CAML in SharePoint Designer you can in fact use those on single-line text fields.

Comment: @ThatGuyYouKnow, This does not work!

Comment: Then you're better off following what @RobertKaucher suggested and going through SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

The really simple answer is to filter on your field using "Is not equal to" and leave the box blank!

I was using Is greater than 0, which sort of worked as well, but led to some errors.